# Json file to MongoDB insert fails

Tags: json, mongodb, bulkinsert

I am using C# to insert a JSON file to MongoDB.I am getting a JSON input file like in the bottom of this question. Table columns and rows may be above hundred. How to insert it as each record in MongoDB? .I am getting the duplicate _id error while inserting with "collection.insertone(document)" command. I cannot create an object list for each table input. Please help!

```
{"name":1,"adduser":4,"amount":49.20,"bankacct":"02201004",.........}
{"name":2,"adduser":5,"amount":22.20,"bankacct":"02201004",.........}
```